# How do I pass the option_from_collection_for_select results in a single param?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, parameters

I have a form where you have to select any number of courses that are prerequisites for certain classes. Basically, course1 -> list of all courses where you choose which ones are prereqs. Then course2 -> and so on. The forms are perfect, but when I submit it, the params in the next page are in a weird format.

```
course[1][]:1
course[1][]:2
course[2][]:2
```

@course is Course.all

```
<% @course.each do |course| %>
<div>
  <%= label_tag "course[#{course.id}]", course.title %>
  <%= select_tag "course[#{course.id}]", options_from_collection_for_select(@course, "id", "title"), multiple: true %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

How can I pass the final params as

```
course[1]: [1, 2]
course[2]: [2]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please replace the select tag with below tag and try.

```
<%= select_tag "course[][#{course.id}]", options_from_collection_for_select(@course, "id", "title"), multiple: true %>
```

I Hope this will help.